# Clojure spec: checking map values directly?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I'm writing a spec for a `square`, which is very simply a pair of integer coordinates (keys `::sq-x` `::sq-y`) combined with a sequential collection of vertices (key `::vtxs`).

Speccing this constraint:

```
(s/def ::square
   (s/and
      map? ; this is probably not needed
      (s/keys :req [::sq-x ::sq-y ::vtxs])))
```

The above checks the presence of the keys only. To also check the key *values*, I add specs *named the same as the keys to be checked*. This implicit link between specs is always live:

```
(s/def ::sq-x ::int-val)
(s/def ::sq-y ::int-val)
(s/def ::vtxs sequential?)
```

In the above `::int-val` is another spec checking value integer-ness (we are basically aliasing the specs: `::sq-x` -> `::int-val`):

```
(s/def ::int-val #(= (Math/floor %) (* 1.0 %)))
```

This works perfectly well. From another package, which imports the package above as `sut` ("system under test"), I can run this test code with err... "good effect on target":

```
(t/deftest test-good-squares
   (t/is (s/valid? ::sut/square 
      { ::sut/sq-x 1   ::sut/sq-y -1  ::sut/vtxs [] }))
   (t/is (s/valid? ::sut/square 
      { ::sut/sq-x 5.0 ::sut/sq-y 5.0 ::sut/vtxs [] }))
   (t/is (s/valid? ::sut/square
      { ::sut/sq-x 0.0 ::sut/sq-y 0.0 ::sut/vtxs [] })))

(t/deftest test-bad-squares-bad-coords
   (t/is (not (s/valid? ::sut/square 
      { ::sut/sq-x 1.1 ::sut/sq-y -1  ::sut/vtxs [] })))
   (t/is (not (s/valid? ::sut/square 
      { ::sut/sq-x -1  ::sut/sq-y 1.1 ::sut/vtxs [] })))
   (t/is (not (s/valid? ::sut/square 
      { ::sut/sq-x 1.1 ::sut/sq-y 1.1 ::sut/vtxs [] }))))

(t/deftest test-bad-squares-bad-vertexes
   (t/is (not (s/valid? ::sut/square
      { ::sut/sq-x 1.1 ::sut/sq-y -1  ::sut/vtxs #{1 2 3} }))))   

(t/deftest test-bad-squares-bad-type
   (t/is (not (s/valid? ::sut/square [:a :b :c]))))

(t/deftest test-bad-squares-missing-keys
   (t/is (not (s/valid? ::sut/square { ::sut/sq-y 0 ::sut/vtxs [] })))
   (t/is (not (s/valid? ::sut/square { ::sut/sq-x 0 ::sut/vtxs [] })))
   (t/is (not (s/valid? ::sut/square { ::sut/vtxs [] }))))

; call the above hierarchically

(t/deftest test-square
   (test-good-squares)
   (test-bad-squares-bad-coords)
   (test-bad-squares-bad-vertexes)
   (test-bad-squares-bad-type)
   (test-bad-squares-missing-keys))

; call ONLY the test-square from "lein test", don't call individual 
; tests a second time

(defn test-ns-hook [] (test-square))
```

So far so good.

**Now, complication:**

Prior to this I had tried to find a way to check the map values directly, without passing via another spec. I didn't find a way to make this palatable to Clojure. For example, this doesn't work:

```
(s/def ::square
   (s/and
      map?
      (s/keys :req [::sq-x ::sq-y ::vtxs])
      (::int-val #(get % ::sq-x))
      (::int-val #(get % ::sq-y))
      (sequential? #(get % ::vtxs))))
```

Runtime is ouch time:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method:
   :specize* of protocol: #'clojure.spec.alpha/Specize found for class: nil
```

Ok. That code looks dodgy. Is there a way to reach into the map directly or am I always supposed to define another spec and call it implicitly through the naming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> am I always supposed to define another spec and call it implicitly through the naming?

To use clojure.spec as intended/designed, the natural approach is to register your key specs as you've done here:

```
(s/def ::sq-x ::int-val)
(s/def ::sq-y ::int-val)
(s/def ::vtxs sequential?)
```

This gives "global" meaning to the keywords `::sq-x`, `::sq-y`, etc. Using this approach allows you to define a `s/keys` spec for a map with those keys:

```
(s/def ::square (s/keys :req [::sq-x ::sq-y ::vtxs]))
```

Then if you conform a map against `::square`, spec will resolve each key's spec (if they exist in the spec registry) and conform each key's value respectively:

```
(s/conform ::square {::sq-x 1 ::sq-y 0 ::vtxs ["hey"]})
```

The intention here is to tie specs to strong names/keywords, so that `::sq-x` means the same thing everywhere (though it's actually `:whatever-namespace-foo/sq-x`.

> Is there a way to reach into the map directly

Yes, you can certainly define custom predicates/functions to inspect/conform whatever data you like. Your example above has a couple issues:

```
 (s/def ::square
   (s/and
     map? ;; unnecessary with s/keys
     (s/keys :req [::sq-x ::sq-y ::vtxs])
     ;; the following forms don't evaluate to functions, so they aren't used as predicates
     (::int-val #(get % ::sq-x))
     (::int-val #(get % ::sq-y))
     (sequential? #(get % ::vtxs))))
```

To get a better sense of that, try evaluating one of the forms individually and see that it evaluates to nil.

```
user=> (::int-val #(get % ::sq-x))
nil
```

What you want instead is a function that will be passed some value and either return a value or perhaps `:clojure.spec.alpha/invalid`. This example would work without registering individual key specs, but I don't think it aligns well with spec's design:

```
(s/def ::square
  (s/and
    (s/keys :req [::sq-x ::sq-y ::vtxs])
    #(= (Math/floor (::sq-x %)) (* 1.0 (::sq-x %)))
    #(= (Math/floor (::sq-y %)) (* 1.0 (::sq-y %)))
    #(sequential? (::vtxs %))))
```

Comment: Ok, got it. So when the "spec evaluation" finds a predicate instead of a "spec constructor", it will pass the thing-to-be-specced. This leads to the following additional possibilites for performing checks within `s/and`: 1) `#(let [a (::sq-x %)] (= (Math/floor a) (* 1.0 a)))` to avoid duplicate get-from-map 2) `#(let [a (::sq-x %)] (s/valid? ::int-val a))` to call an existing spec in the guise of a predicate 3) `#(s/valid? ::int-val (::sq-x %))` which is just 2) without the `let`.

Answer (score 2):

I would just define the specs using the build-in function `int?`:

```
(s/def ::sq-x int?)
```

See:  https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_composing_predicates for details.

However, it is intended with spec for each item in a collection to have a "type", so specs can be re-used.  So an `::address` spec might be composed of `::number`, `::street`, `::city`, `::state`, and `::zip`.

See:  https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_entity_maps

---

**Update:**

I wrote a more general-purpose integer-value testing function:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t]))

 (defn int-val?
   "Returns true iff arg is an integer value of any Clojure/Java type
   (all int types, float/double, BigInt/BigInteger, BigDecimal, clojure.lang.Ratio)."
   [x]
   (cond
     (or (int? x) (integer? x)) true

     ; handles both java.lang.Float & java.lang.Double types
     (float? x) (let [x-dbl (double x)] (= x-dbl (Math/floor x-dbl)))

     (bigdecimal? x) (try
                       (let [bi-val (.toBigIntegerExact x)]
                         ; no exception => fraction was zero
                         true)
                       (catch Exception e
                         ; exception => fraction was non-zero
                         false))
     (ratio? x) (zero? (mod x 1))
     :else (throw (ex-info "Invalid type" {:x x}))))

(dotest
    (is (not= 5 5.0))

    (is (int-val? 5))
    (is (int-val? 5.0))
    (is (int-val? 5N))
    (is (int-val? 5M))
    (is (int-val? (bigdec 5)))
    (is (int-val? (bigint 5)))
    (is (int-val? (biginteger 5)))

    (is (int-val? (* 3 (/ 5 3)) ))

    (throws? (int-val? "five")))
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, but I wanted to "accept an integer value, even if typed as double", and `(int? 4.0) ;=> false`. And then I got interested in how to do speccing of the values explicitly, instead of implicity, hence the question.

Comment: `(= x (int x)))` is no-go because `int` casts to integer: `(#(= % (int %)) 6.0)
 ;=> false`. Symmetrically, `floor` casts to `double`: `(#(= % (Math/floor %)) 6) ;=> false`. You really have to `or` both cases: `(#(or (= % (Math/floor %)) (= % (int %))) 6) ;=> true` and identically `(#(or (= % (Math/floor %)) (= % (int %))) 6.0) ;=> true`